# Multiple records to a single record in PIG

Tags: apache-pig

I've input file as below.

```
1,Cust_name1,addr_type,Addr1
1,Cust_name1,addr_type,Addr2
2,Cust_name3,addr_type,Addr1
2,Cust_name3,addr_type,Addr3
```

Want to convert this to `Avro` format.

output should be like

```
1,Cust_name1,{(addr_type,Addr1),(addr_type,Addr2)
1,Cust_name3,{(addr_type,Addr1),(addr_type,Addr3)
```

For each customer I want generate a single message in avro and repeated elements in array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GROUP by Id and Customer Name.In order to store in Avro format use AvroStorage available in piggybank.jar and register it in your script.It can downloaded from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pig/piggybank/0.15.0)

```
REGISTER /path/piggybank.jar;
A = LOAD 'data.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (int:id;name:chararray;addrtype:chararray;addr:chararray);
B = GROUP A BY (id,name);
STORE B INTO '/path/' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage();;
```

Comment: Currently in output I am getting group by columns also part of array so Included one more step after group by X = FOREACH B GENERATE group, A.(st_date,country_code,phone); but while storing  X using STORE X INTO 'Avro_out21' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage(); getting container error. please check

Comment: That is not a script error but most likely its the YARN container.Ask your cluster admin to resolve it.